# Configuration changes remove my favorite state for items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

**I have items on a list and each item has some properties. One of them is favorite property. I can add item to favorite and see it on favorite screen without any problem, but when I click on an item which is already favorite and change some changes(for example change author), after this my favorite screen remove and item will come back to none favorite**

I created gist for it, because there are many stuffs behind on that (if you need I can add another classes as well):  https://gist.github.com/oolyvi/dbffd5f838565daddc977156145b478f

Sample video:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a8zA.gif)

Comment: Can you add code related to book edit view. From gif, it can be assumed that only that item is removed from favourites which has been edited. So, maybe isFavourite value is being changed to false from EditBookView!

Comment: I added this gist to many files, which involves everything about favorites. I think it will help you to find a solution. Link:  https://gist.github.com/oolyvi/e7b87ba86c2783b29b4ecac0b718c32c